# Не могу запустить ни один bat/cmd в Windows

Tags: windows, cmd, реестр

Пытался запустить локально созданный файл startkali.bat. Код:

```
@echo off
bash
```

Но при обычном запуске, пишет, что

```
Windows не удается получить к указанному устройству, пути или файлу. Возможно, у вас нет нужных разрешений
```

Пробовал менять реестр: перешел по пути `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`. Было:

```
ComSpec   REG_EXPAND_SZ   %SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe
```

Я пересоздал его, сделав `REG_SZ`. Не помогло. Смотрю права на cmd.exe и conhost.exe - ну, выполнять их может кто угодно, права на исполнение есть. Меняю обратно на `REG_EXPAND_SZ` - не спасло. Если выбрать запуск от имени администратора, или же напрямую из cmd/PowerShell - все работает. Что делать?

Comment: 1. Зачем тебе в винде баш? 2. Ты посмотрел сериал "Мистер робот" и пришёл сюда?

Comment: ```bash``` у меня запускает WSL (понятно по названию скрипта). и да, до ОС прошу не дое...ться

Comment: и суть в том, что я вообще не могу bat/cmd запускать.

Comment: Ну так запускай wsl, в чём проблема?

Comment: `до ОС прошу не дое...ться`, я надеюсь, ты понимаешь, что кали - очень специфичный дистрибутив, предназначенный для узкого круга специалистов внутри IT? Я бы на твоём месте немного поменял бы стек на более дружелюбный.

Comment: don Rumata, у меня вообще bat-ники не работают, в этом вся проблема

Comment: don Rumata, 1) Kali впринципе я юзаю из-за нормального софта (в отличие от Arch, Alpine, где с этим туго) и rolling-release (не присуще Debian и Ubuntu). А как десктоп - тем более юзаю Kali, ибо мне ещё дрова на WiFi нужны+ некоторые пентест утилиты. Я бы максимум перешёл с Kali на Gentoo - но нету времени морочить себе этим голову.